# Docker Packages: Hash Sum Mismatch

Tags: docker, ubuntu-14.04, apt-get

I am getting the following error while doing apt-get update (Ubuntu 14.04)

```
Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com trusty/main amd64 Packages                       
Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com trusty/restricted amd64 Packages                 
Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com trusty/universe amd64 Packages                   
Fetched 3156 kB in 15s (201 kB/s)                                              
W: **Failed to fetch https://apt.dockerproject.org/repo/dists/ubuntu-trusty/main/binary-amd64/Packages  Hash Sum mismatch**

E: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.
```

Answer (score 1):

Did you add the gpg key of docker repo?

From the official [doc](https://docs.docker.com/engine/installation/linux/ubuntulinux/):

`$ sudo apt-key adv --keyserver hkp://p80.pool.sks-keyservers.net:80 --recv-keys 58118E89F3A912897C070ADBF76221572C52609D`

Answer (score 1):

This is a known bug in docker currently, see [here](https://github.com/docker/docker/issues/23203#issue-158122733).

There are a few workarounds listed in that thread, depending on where you are hitting this problem (travis CI is different than locally).

Answer (score 0):

The chosen solution didn't work for me. And I noticed that this isn't always the case - that is, if I wait a day or two, I don't get the error. I suspect it has more to do with the ubuntu repositories than the version of docker we use (as explained by [Robie](https://askubuntu.com/a/160179/808341)).

My solution is to use one of the [official mirrors](http://mirrors.ubuntu.com/mirrors.txt) instead of the default ubuntu repo. **Replace xenial with your ubuntu version. You might need an extra deb-src line for all or none of the lines depending on where you are getting the mismatch.** I noticed that the mirrors are slower compared to the default.

```
RUN rm -rf /etc/apt/sources.list
RUN echo "deb mirror://mirrors.ubuntu.com/mirrors.txt xenial main restricted universe multiverse" >> /etc/apt/sources.list
RUN echo "deb mirror://mirrors.ubuntu.com/mirrors.txt xenial-updates main restricted universe multiverse" >> /etc/apt/sources.list
RUN echo "deb-src mirror://mirrors.ubuntu.com/mirrors.txt xenial-updates main restricted universe multiverse" >> /etc/apt/sources.list
RUN echo "deb mirror://mirrors.ubuntu.com/mirrors.txt xenial-backports main restricted universe multiverse" >> /etc/apt/sources.list
RUN echo "deb mirror://mirrors.ubuntu.com/mirrors.txt xenial-security main restricted universe multiverse" >> /etc/apt/sources.list
```